# Appending to StringBuilder while there is nothing left

Tags: c#

I have to the task to rearrange the words in a sentence backwards, but i am able to do it only for the first letter.Example: Fun exam right.What i have until now:

```
var sentance = Console.Readline().Split(' ');
var rearrangedSentence = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0,i<sentance.Lenght,i++)
   {
       rearrangedSentence.Append(sentance[i].Last());//this gives me "nmt"
   }
```

My question is how to make this loop repeat itself while there is nothing left.
Any help will be greatly appriciated :)

**EDIT: Question is**

> I mean if i have the sentence "Fun exam right" the result should be :nmtuahFxgeir . We first take the last chars of each word append that results in "nmt" then take the next one and add them resulting in "nmtuah" and so on

Comment: I am confused about the requirement. Is it "This is a test" => "test a is This" or => "tset a si sihT" ?

Comment: take a closer look at the variables (using var all the time will make you forget what is in them) .. you dont want it repeating when theres nothng you need for each word to reverse it.. how would you do that if I gave you batches of scrabble letters?

Comment: Very bad description of your requirement. _" i am able to do it only for the first letter."_ It seems you are just outputting the last letters of each word but in forward direction. What you actually need?

Comment: ... or is it "This is a test" => "sihT si a tset" ?

Comment: I mean if i have the sentence "Fun exam right" the result should be :nmtuahFxgeir . We first take the last chars of each word append that results in "nmt" then take the next one and add them resulting in "nmtuah" and so on

Comment: @GeorgiDelchev Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man. Works perfectly and your explanation is very helpful. Only 1 question : Why not increase x in the inner loop ?

Comment: Inner loop traverses length of sentence array, not the word length for position of val. We can do a bit of manipulation here and use i also, but this is easier.

Comment: I see. In order not to do additional work we do it there,because it won't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `sentance[i].Last()`, you are only picking up the last element of your array.

EDIT: As per your updated requirements, you can use this code.

```
           //Get the sentence array
            var sentence = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            var rearrangedSentence = new StringBuilder();

           //Get the length of longest word in array
            int loopLength = sentence.OrderBy(n => n.Length).Last().Length;


            int x = 0;
           // Run for the length of longest word
            for (int i = loopLength-1; i >=0 ; i--)
            {
               // need to pick up an element at every run for each element.
                for (var j = 0; j < sentence.Length; j++)
                {
                    //Picking the position of item to be picked up   
                    int val = sentence[j].Length - (x + 1);
                    // If index not out of bounds
                    if(val >= 0 && val <= sentence[j].Length)
                     {
                        // Pick the character and append to stringbuilder.
                        rearrangedSentence.Append(sentence[j][val]);
                     }
                }
               // Next letter should be n-1, then n-2. 
               // Increase this. Val will decrease
                x++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(rearrangedSentence.ToString());


            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: There is even [Arrays.Reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Fildor Yes, that is also an option, but person asking question wants a fix with StringBuilder. Also, after Array.Reverse, Array Join will be required.

Comment: _" wants a fix with StringBuilder"_ - I am not sure he actually 100% knows what he wants.

Comment: @Fildor appended your suggestion also.

Comment: I approached it with StringBuilder because that was my first thought for taking individual chars.If there are better options please share :)